# how to log to a file with Deno

Tags: logging, deno

I do not understand the deno logging api. Can someone explain it?
I am trying to log all of my messages(error, warning, info, etc...) to a single file. It would be nice to have a time stamp too.

Here is some code which is basically from the example in the docs. **Nothing** is getting written to the log file.

```
import * as log from "https://deno.land/std/log/mod.ts";

async function startLogger() {
  await log.setup({
    handlers: {
      console: new log.handlers.ConsoleHandler("DEBUG"),

      file: new log.handlers.FileHandler("WARNING", {
        filename: "./logTest.txt",
        // you can change format of output message using any keys in `LogRecord`
        formatter: "{levelName} {msg}",
      }),
    },

    loggers: {
      // configure default logger available via short-hand methods above
      default: {
        level: "DEBUG",
        handlers: ["console", "file"],
      },

      tasks: {
        level: "ERROR",
        handlers: ["console"],
      },
    },
  });
      // get default logger
      const logger = log.getLogger();
      return logger
}

var logger = await startLogger()

logger.debug('debug should this show up in a file?')
logger.error('error should this show up in a file?')
logger.warning('warn should this show up in a file?')
logger.info('warn should this show up in a file?')
```

```
deno run --allow-write --allow-read testLogger.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileHandler` flushes to disk every 30 seconds. If you wait 30 seconds you'll see that data is being written.

From the documentation:

> This handler uses a buffer for writing to file and will automatically
>   flush every 30 seconds, though you can trigger this yourself with
>   `fileHandler.flush()`. Log messages with a log level greater than
>   error are immediately flushed.

Comment: So it looks like only Errors and Warnings are getting logged to the file. Why are not debug messages?

Comment: because you have `WARNING` in your `FileHandler` level.

Comment: How would I get everything including debug and info to go to a file?

Comment: use `DEBUG` instead of `WARNING` on your FileHandler setup.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Even after 30 seconds, my log file is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because there no fileHandler.flush();

```
import { setup, handlers, getLogger } from "https://deno.land/std@0.158.0/log/mod.ts";

const fileHandler = new handlers.FileHandler("INFO", {
    filename: 'log/info.log',
});

setup({
    handlers: {
        writeTofile: fileHandler
    },
    loggers: {
        default: {
          level: "INFO",
          handlers: ["writeTofile"],
        },
    },
});

const logger = getLogger();
logger.info('Hello world');
fileHandler.flush();
```